# athorization user in asp.net identity and redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identity and have problem in Unauthorize user redirect to login page.
I mean Unathorize user don't redirect to login page.
pleas help

Comment: If unauthorized, what action do you want to take instead of redirecting to Login page?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Seeing as you haven't provided much info I'm assuming you've got a folder `SomeFolder` which contains Member only pages. In that folder have a `web.config` file and use the code below

So you want something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

`<deny users="?"/>` means deny unauthenticated users

Comment: thanks for reply but I set this code . I mean asp.net identity don't redirect the Unathorize user to login page.

Comment: I user Url Routing .when I request that page have permission adminstrator with route url I get error like this


An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.

when I request that page without using route url , redirect correctly me to login page .

Comment: Give your folder(s) the appropriate  permissions. `Network Service` and `IIS_IUSRS`